# Z3 Python exclude tracker variables from solution

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm using the Z3 Python API and I have the following code to get unsatisfiable cores:

```
for idx, constr in enumerate(z3constrs):
    solver.assert_and_track(constr, f'tracker{idx}')
```

However, the model's solution contains the tracker variables:

```
>>> print(solver.model())
[tracker71 = True,
 tracker229 = True,
 rect11_x1 = 35,
 ...]
```

Is there any way to remove these variables from the solution (while keeping it a `ModelRef` object) without running the solver twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. These variables are part of the model, and thus their presence is important when you use `solver.model()` result in other calls, such as `m.evaluate(expr)`. So, you cannot "ignore" them, while still keeping the result as a `ModelRef`.

But you can ask the question, why do you need the result to be a `ModelRef` in that case? By eliminating tracker-variables, you're violating internal invariants about how the models are constructed. If your concern is simply to not display them in a model or pass around a data-structure that contains everything but trackers, then the typical thing to do is to simply create a list of pairs and use that instead. Here's an example:

```py
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
s = Solver()
s.assert_and_track(a > 3, 'tracker1')
s.check()
m = s.model()
clean_m = []
for d in m.decls():
    if not(d.name().startswith("tracker")):
       clean_m += [(d, m[d])]
print(m)
print(clean_m)
```

This prints:

```py
[tracker1 = True, a = 4]
[(a, 4)]
```

Obviously, you can post-process the results further to shape them in any-way you want.